# Tool for transitioning to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I want to transition my App to `ARC`. I can change `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` to `YES` but that does not automatically remove `release`s `retain`s etc.

The [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) states:

> Xcode has a new tool that automates the mechanical parts of the ARC conversion (such as removing retain and release calls) and helps you to fix issues the migrator can’t handle automatically. The migration tool converts all files in a project to use ARC. You can also choose to use ARC on a per-file basis if it’s more convenient for you to use manual reference counting for some files.

How do I invoke this tool in Xcode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh man I just found it:

> Convert > **To Objective-C ARC**

I checked in Xcode's help first where I could not find it.

[image]

Comment: If you find difficulty in searching anything in xcode... just go to xcode help and use search, It is so good.

Comment: In addition you'll want to change the settings so that it will build after errors. Go to XCode > Preferences > General  and check "Continue building after errors". This way you can see all the errors you'll need to fix to work with ARC.